# How to split BGR (raw) image into N number of equal images

Tags: image-processing

Task at hand is to split an available BGR(raw) image into N equal number image. Can someone give me hint on storage of BGR -raw images in memory

For example:
If I have 1920 * 1080 pixels BGR image, and I would like to split it into 8 equal parts then is there any available framework that can help me. I'm trying to write native CPP code on Android, working with OpenCV would be expensive to do, any other alternative

Comment: Your question is impossibly vague and lacking detail. What processing software? What OS? Why are you splitting? You need to improve it fast or it will get closed.

Comment: Still not very clear, but maybe you could use `CImg` which is a header-only (no libraries to link against) C++ image processing library - see http://cimg.eu